# Problem executing local and global variables with exec() in Python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, exec

I am trying to execute the code:

```
def test_exec():
  df1 = df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1, 2, 3, 4],
                        "b":[5, 6, 7, 8]})
  df2 = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1, 2, 3],
                    "b":[5, 6, 7]})
  formula = "concat = pd.concat([df1,df2],ignore_index=True)"
  exec(formula,globals())
  print(concat)
```

And I get the error:

[image]

Note: I need to use the exec() function in the middle of the code, getting variables previously declared in the code and generating the final variable "concat".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. It is necessary to define the local variables as a dictionary.

PS. In this example I used pd.concat(...), so it is necessary, in the str, to import pandas as pd.

```
def test_exec():
  df1 = df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1, 2, 3, 4],
                        "b":[5, 6, 7, 8]})
  df2 = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1, 2, 3],
                    "b":[5, 6, 7]})
  
  locals_dict = {}
  formula = 'import pandas as pd; concat = pd.concat([df1,df2],ignore_index=True)'
  exec(formula,locals(),locals_dict)
  concat = locals_dict['concat']
  print(concat)
```

Comment: Glad you solved it! Please mark your answer as correct so others can see it on the first glance that you solved your problem!